# $\frac{a_{n}}{1+a_{n}}\rightarrow0$ yields $a_{n}\rightarrow0$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Is my proof correct ? $$$$
Suppose that $a_{n}$ doesn't convergent to $0$. So, there exist partial limit $L\neq0$ of $a_{n}$, suppose $a_{n_{k}}\rightarrow L$.
Then: $$\frac{a_{n_{k}}}{1+a_{n_{k}}}\rightarrow\frac{L}{1+L}\neq0$$
in contradiction.

Comment: What if $L=-1$?

Comment: Why is it special ? $\frac{-1}{1-1}=\infty\neq0$

Comment: @DanielPollak You just went full rambo and divided by $0$...

Comment: It's not really dividing by zero, it's approaching a division by zero.

Comment: Try to multiply the limit with $1=\frac{1/a_n}{1/a_n}$

Comment: Another approach may be to observe that $\left(\frac{a_n + 1}{a_n}\right)^{-1} = \left(1 + \frac{1}{a_n}\right)^{-1} \to 0$

Comment: Is there something wrong with me proof ? didn't get you guys..

Comment: Yes there was a topological mistake, see my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**A simple proof:**
$\dfrac{a_n}{1+a_n}=b_n\to 0$ then $a_n=\dfrac{b_n}{1-b_n}\to 0$

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that your sequence $a_n$ is guaranteed to have a convergent subsequence only if bounded (think of $a_n = n$).

Take the absolute value of your reaction, divide numerator and denominator by $a_n$ and inverse it and you get $|1+1/a_n| \rightarrow +\infty$. Conclude

Comment: I didn't claimed that $L$ is finite. If $L$ is infinite it is still a contradiction, isn't it ?

Comment: Then fine. Not my style as you need to distinguish three cases on L (finite, -1 and infinite) but it works